# Is there risk of damage if I power a fan with my bench supply but connect the yellow wire to a fan header on a computer that has its own power supply?

Tags: power-supply, safety, fan

I'm trying to debug an issue with a fan's voltage and how the motherboard handles the tachometer. I want to power the fan from my bench supply to give it a constant 5v but connect the yellow pin to the motherboard which uses its own power supply.

As long as I take the necessary precautions so that I'm not making a short anywhere, is there any risk of the power from my bench supply leaking through the yellow sense while and causing damage to the computer?

Comment: can you post a schematic of what you want to do? I am not sure if i understood how you want to wire.

Answer (score 0):

They must share the same 0V ground to function otherwise the isolation is unlikely to cause damage since the high insulation impedance cannot conduct much current (< xx uAac)

Answer (score 0):

You must connect the power supply ground/- to the computer ground/- so everything has the same Zero volt reference..